# How make a WP custom Gutemberg block with a drag and drop sorting?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Here’s a question for both WP and React developers. I want to develop a custom Gutemberg block using the official create-block library. For UX reasons, I would like this block to have a drag-and-drop sorting system, like [this gif](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25527820/61283538-36186b80-a7b5-11e9-80bc-bfac44628f9a.gif). But I haven’t found a solution. There’s this library https://github.com/lucprincen/gutenberg-sortable, but it’s obsolete and won’t compile.

Any ideas? Here’s a simplified code that you can improve.

```
import { registerBlockType } from "@wordpress/blocks";
import "./style.scss";
import metadata from "./block.json";
import { useBlockProps } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

registerBlockType(metadata.name, {
    attributes: {
        items: {
            type: "array",
            default: ["carrot", "cabbage", "zucchini"],
        },
    },

    edit: (props) => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();
        const {
            attributes: { items },
            setAttributes,
        } = props;

        const sortItems = (sortedItems) => {
            setAttributes({ items: sortedItems });
        };

        return (
            <div {...blockProps}>
                {items.map((item) => (
                    <div className="item">{item}</div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    },

    save: (props) => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
        const {
            attributes: { items },
        } = props;

        return (
            <div {...blockProps}>
                {items.map((item) => (
                    <div className="item">{item}</div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking so hard and i find a solution :). The best thing to do is to use Gutenberg's native drag and drop. I've developed two custom blocks. A parent block and a child block. The parent block has an innerBlock which can only receive child blocks. Here's the simplified code.

**parent block.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "domain/vegetables",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Vegetables",
    "category": "text",
    "icon": "carrot",
    "description": "A sortable list of vegetables",
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css"
}
```

**parent index.js**

```
import { registerBlockType } from "@wordpress/blocks";
import metadata from "./block.json";
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

registerBlockType(metadata, {
    edit: () => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();

        return (
            <div {...blockProps}>
                <InnerBlocks
                    allowedBlocks={["domain/vegetable"]}
                    template={[["domain/vegetable"]]}
                />
            </div>
        );
    },

    save: (props) => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();

        return (
            <div {...blockProps}>
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

**child block.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "domain/vegetable",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Vegetable",
    "category": "text",
    "icon": "carrot",
    "parent": ["domain/vegetables"],
    "description": "A vegetable",
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "attributes": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css"
}
```

**child index.js**

```
import { registerBlockType } from "@wordpress/blocks";
import metadata from "./block.json";
import { useBlockProps, RichText } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

registerBlockType(metadata, {
    edit: (props) => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();
        const {
            attributes: { name },
            setAttributes,
        } = props;

        return (
            <div {...blockProps}>
                <RichText
                    {...blockProps}
                    tagName="p"
                    value={name}
                    allowedFormats={[]}
                    onChange={(name) => setAttributes({ name })}
                    placeholder={"A vegetable..."}
                />
            </div>
        );
    },

    save: (props) => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
        const {
            attributes: { name },
        } = props;

        return (
            <div {...blockProps}>
                <p>{name}</p>
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```